# Setting static IPv4 address says "has host bits set."

Tags: networking, server

My dedicated server comes with 4 usable ip addresses and this is all the info they sent me.

```
System IP: 69.30.212.170/29
Usable IP Range: 69.30.212.170 - 69.30.212.174
Gateway: 69.30.212.169
Subnet Mask:255.255.255.248
```

However, when I put the system IP into the subnet, (subnet mask doesn't work either) it says "has host bits set". Here is a screenshot:
[image: error screenshot]

Is there anything I can do to fix this? If there is, what is it?

Comment: this is an ubuntu installer, and plus i showed all the info and comes with no subnet

Comment: google "ubuntu 18.04 server install". I'll wait.

Comment: When it comes to IPv4 Subnetting etc I like to use http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Answer (score 9):

I got the problem. Enter there

```
69.30.212.168/29
```

Hosts bits should be unset.

Your hosts bits are the last 3 bits. If you set them to 0, that will get 168.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Note that if your subnet mask is lower than `24` you will need to zero out the 3rd byte in the IP too, e.g. `69.30.0.0/16`. (Likewise for the 2nd byte, I imagine, if your subnet mask is lower than `16`.)

Comment: Thank you, James. Answered my question.

Comment: I think the common problem here comes from the fact that most of the time people would have to enter a **subnet mask** rather than the **subnet** itself. I have no idea why Canonical decided to do this the other way around. In the end though the mask is included (here `/29`).

Comment: Just another basic example, using ipv4 192.168.86.2-254 in a SOHO router, subnet would be 192.168.86.0/24, gateway 192.168.86.1